# Websphere - How to switch JSF implementation to DEFAULT on admin console?

Tags: jsf, websphere

As part of my application setup i have mistakenly changed the JSF implementation on WAS admin console from DEFAULT to SunRI1.2 which is causing issues while running the application. I get Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/ws/webcontainer/srt/SRTServletResponse and i assume it's due to the change i made. I need to change it back to DEFAULT but couldn't do it.

These are steps i've followed to set it to SunRI1.2

```
set server [$AdminConfig list ApplicationServer *server1*]
$AdminConfig modify $server {{jsfProvider SunRI1.2}}
$AdminConfig save

Doing the following doesn't set it back to DEFAULT. 
set server [$AdminConfig list ApplicationServer *server1*]
$AdminConfig modify $server {{jsfProvider DEFAULT}
$AdminConfig save
```

Appreciate your help on this, many thanks

Comment: This question might better fit to https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a WAS 8 or higher, `MyFaces` is the default value - setting that value will get you the equivalent of `DEFAULT`

```
$AdminConfig modify $server {{jsfProvider MyFaces}}
$AdminConfig save
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer, I have followed the link and issued $AdminConfig remove $server hoping it will remove the config but I couldn't access the admin console after and getting 'Cannot reach this page' error message. Any idea?

Comment: Apologies - I've just tested this, and setting `jsfProvider MyFaces` is the correct thing to do here.  I will update my answer to remove the part about removing config objects.